# Is there a way to run a script on iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

I need to define a processing rule for web data in iOS and thought it would be a good idea to pull the processing rule as a script file from my server and execute it on the iOS device, since the web API I'm interacting with might change URLs or response syntax and I need to be able to fix such issues fast and cannot rely on pushing an update (takes forever).

I wanted to do it with a small `JS` file that is pulled from my server every once and a while, but unfortunately iOS doesn't include the `JavaScriptCore` framework.

Are there other options?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apple developer agreement will not let you run a downloaded, interpreted script, on the device.

Your best bet is probably downloading a data structure (potentially in JSON format) and parse that and take some predefined actions in your client code based on that, rather than trying to execute the downloaded code directly.

Comment: @ErikAigner You can try to technically circumvent the Apple agreement by building an interpreter and hope they don't catch it, but you might have a hard time doing that. The real problem is more contractual than technical. You are sleeping on their bed; they can kick you out anytime they want.

Answer (score 4):

You can let a UIWebView run a Javascript snippet, or you could use another scripting language like LUA (don't forget to add LUA for this). The real problem is: You are not allowed to download code from a webserver or somewhere else. Everything must either be already on the device, or calculated at runtime.

Depending on the information that you want, you could use an XML file that includes the new URLs and parse it, but I don't know if this fits your need.

Comment: I was afraid that it might be prohibited by Apple, so what I thought of as an alternative was to host my own web API and redirect the requests with my API to the original API/Site, so I can adapt fast if the source changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can [**compile JavaScriptCore into your app**](https://github.com/charlietuna/JavaScriptCore-iOS), evidently, and [**have it approved by Apple**](http://www.phoboslab.org/log/2011/04/ios-and-javascript-for-real-this-time). However, as Mehrdad notes, any scripts run in the app *must already be in the app* at the time the app is reviewed.